# Add a custom "Buy now" button on WooCommerce single product page which clears the cart, add a product and redirect to checkout

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, product, checkout

I'm using this simple code to add a 'buy now' button on a single product page.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart' ); 
function add_content_after_addtocart() {
    // get the current post/product ID
    $current_product_id = get_the_ID();

    // get the product based on the ID
    $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );

    // get the "Checkout Page" URL
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    
    // run only on simple products
    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        echo '<a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'" class="mongo_single_add_to_cart_button button">Buy Now</a>';
    }
}
```

This code effectively redirects to the checkout page and add the product to the cart, but I want to add two little features to it:

1. After clicking on the button, I want it to clear the cart before taking the action.
2. After adding the product to the cart, I want it to redirect users to *'/checkout'* page. Right now it sends users on *'checkout/?add-to-cart=3122'*, which means that any refresh on the checkout page adds 1 product on the cart automatically.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `add-to-cart` param in your url, which will cause the product to be added (but also perform other actions in WooCommerce), you can use a custom url for your button and the `template_redirect` action hook

That way you get rid of the built-in functionality in WooCommerce and you can perform your own custom actions based on the GET parameters

So you get:

```php
// Add new/extra button
function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Run only on simple products
        if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
            // Get product ID
            $product_id = $product->get_id();

            // Get permalink
            $permalink = $product->get_permalink();

            // Output url
            echo '<a href="' . $permalink . '?product_id=' . $product_id . '&redirect_checkout=true" class="mongo_single_add_to_cart_button button">'. __ ( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10 );

// Redirect
function action_template_redirect() {
    // Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    // Returns true when viewing a single product
    if ( ! is_product() ) return;

    // Get params
    if ( isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) && isset( $_GET['redirect_checkout'] ) ) {
        // Get param 1
        $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];

        // Get param 2
        $boolean = $_GET['redirect_checkout'];

        // WC Cart
        if ( WC()->cart ) {
            // 1. Empty cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();

            // 2. Add to cart
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

            // 3. Redirect
            // When true
            if ( $boolean ) {
                // Gets the url to the checkout page
                $checkout_url = wc_get_checkout_url();

                // Performs a safe (local) redirect
                wp_safe_redirect( $checkout_url );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'action_template_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for clear cart before add item

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'ji_remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
function ji_remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
return $passed;}
```

2. After adding the product to the cart, I want it to redirect users to '/checkout' page. Right now it sends users on 'checkout/?add-to-cart=3122', which means that any refresh on the checkout page adds 1 product on the cart automatically.

   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'ji_redirect_checkout_after_add_to_cart' );

   function ji_redirect_checkout_after_add_to_cart() {
   return wc_get_checkout_url();
   }

Comment: Thank you, but my goal is to clear the cart only if a user clicks on 'buy now' button. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes for that you need to register new ajax action and call that action when click on buy now button.